# Python route with name is not working but simple routing is working on server, However on local host it is working fine

Tags: python, http, flask, routes

I just make a python application and it is working fine on my localhost but on the server it runs the simple route ('/') but with the name ('/hello') it is not working,
My hosting is shared Cpanel lined server
The Error I got from the logs is

> **The application process exited prematurely.**

Here is my Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import bs4 as bs
import os
import requests
import json

from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('_file_'))
template_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'templates')
static_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'static')

app = Flask(_name_, template_folder=template_path, static_folder=static_path)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True


@app.route("/hello")

def index():
    try:
      return "hello"
    except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            return e

if _name_ == "_main_":
   app.run(debug=True, 
         host='0.0.0.0', 
         port=9000, 
         threaded=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing the .htaccess and putting this line of code in it

```
RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteBase /
```

and it works!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see an example of the code that works with `/`. I suspect that the issue is not changing `/` to `/hello`, but rather something else.

The error message "The application process exited prematurely." sounds like there is probably a syntax error in your code. Instead of running it via cPanel, have you tried executing it from the command line?

After installing your dependencies and trying to run your code, I get this error:

```
-> % python foo.py         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 12, in <module>
    app = Flask(_name_, template_folder=template_path, static_folder=static_path)
NameError: name '_name_' is not defined
```

After correcting all instances of `_name_` to `__name__` and `_main_` to `__main__` your code runs and I can access the endpoint `/hello`. You can read more about `'__main__'` in the Python docs: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/**main**.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)